# How to load a kivy app when physical button is pressed using raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I am currently developing a raspberry pi powered doorbell. I am using a physical button connected via GPIO as the actual doorbell. When this is pressed I wish to initiate the kivy app that I have made which will then display various options and can call functions etc.

```
while True:
    print ("Please Press Door Bell to Begin")
    if GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING):
        introduction()
```

The introduction() being called is the kivy build class:

```
class introduction(App):
   def build(self):
       return InitialMenu()
```

This obviously is not the correct way to go as the class is run at the start as can be seen from console:

```
INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-09-29_28.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1.dev0, git-1e6c9e8, 20170927
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
Please Press Door Bell to Begin
```

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas or workarounds that can be tried to get this to run or if I am missing something glaringly. I feel that just running the Kivy app initially and leaving it running may be a final resort option, however, trying to avoid this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those log lines are triggered by Kivy-related imports, not by running the app.

In your example you would never actually run the App class, because to do that you need to call its `run` method: `introduction().run()`.

Comment: That would very much be the issue, thank you very much Inclement.